# How to fix 'Attribute is a namespace but is used like a type' error in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, attributes

I tried to inherit 'attribute' to a class but I could not do that. Basically, I created a new class which is RequiredPropertyAttribute and I tried to add : Attribute to make inheritance. However, :Attribute has red underline.

```
       [AttributeUsage(Inherited =true)]
       class RequiredPropertyAttribute : Attribute //There is a problem.
       {

       }

       [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class,AllowMultiple = true)]
       class ToTableAttribute : Attribute //There is also a problem.
       {
           string _tableName;
           public ToTableAttribute(string tableName)
           {
               _tableName = tableName;
           }
       }
```

{ } namespace Attribute

'Attribute' is a namespace but used like a type.

Comment: **Why did you add `: Attribute` to your class definition?** Can you explain why you did that? You wanted to inherit something from somebody. Can you tell us *what* you wanted to inherit?

Comment: Why is your namespace named `Attribute`, because it's assuming that you are attempting to inherit from the namespace rather than the class, `System.Attribute`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining your classes in the namespace named `Attribute`.

Try one of the following:

1. Change your namespace name to something else.
2. Inherit from `System.Attribute`.

Answer (score 0):

Am assuming that the namespace in which those 2 classes are in is named `Attribute` so the full code would be:

```
namespace Attribute
{
   [AttributeUsage(Inherited =true)]
   class RequiredPropertyAttribute : Attribute //There is a problem.
   {

   }

   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class,AllowMultiple = true)]
   class ToTableAttribute : Attribute //There is also a problem.
   {
       string _tableName;
       public ToTableAttribute(string tableName)
       {
           _tableName = tableName;
       }
   }
}
```

And if not like that, and the classes are not part of a namespace then there is a namespace else where, either in your project or a referenced dll, whose name is `Attribute`. Basically, the reason the above isn't working is because IntelliSense is assuming that your classes are inheriting from the namespace named `Attribute` rather then the class `System.Attribute`. So to fix this all you would need to do is either change the namespace's name or prepend to the `Attribute`s, after the colons, `System.` so your fixed code would be like this:

```
namespace Attribute //This should be renamed instead or else for every attribute class you create you will need to specify "System.Attribute" as the base
{
   [AttributeUsage(Inherited =true)]
   class RequiredPropertyAttribute : System.Attribute //Will tell IntelliSense that your class is inheriting from the Attribute class rather than the above namespace
   {

   }

   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class,AllowMultiple = true)]
   class ToTableAttribute : System.Attribute
   {
       string _tableName;
       public ToTableAttribute(string tableName)
       {
           _tableName = tableName;
       }
   }
}
```